# AWS SOA record from AWS to Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, cloudflare, soa-record

I purchase a domain with AWS to try it out and edited the `NS records` with CloudFlare records, but I also have another entry for `SOA`, this is it:

```
Record type
SOA – Start of authority record
ns-501.awsdns-62.com. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com 1234...
```

How do I migrate this record to CloudF?

Unfortunately, I can’t just delete the `SOA` record in AWS, it doesn’t allow me to delete it, it’s a must. Now… if I delete it’s content look what happens:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utuA2.png)

A filed is required. I also tried to put the NS records and id didn’t like it.

So how do I handle this record?

These are the two defaults:
[image](https://i.postimg.cc/nVGjFCpV/Screen-Shot-2021-01-18-at-5-18-44-PM.png)

Clarification: I want to use Cloudflare as my DNS provider while having the domain purchased with Amazon.

Thanks

Comment: CloudFlare supports purchasing a domain: https://www.cloudflare.com/products/registrar/

Comment: Even though it says registrar, I can't find an option to purchase it. Anyway, that's out of topic

Comment: Forget SOA and all that and tell us **what are you trying to achieve** from the business perspective. What's the desired outcome? Because it's not clear from the question and deleting SOA will hardly achieve anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it, this is the actual page where the records are changed:

[image: someone with more stack points modify this to show image please]

As you can see in the image above on the top right corner I can edit the DNS records and point to CloudFlare.

Comment: You DO have to edit it in both places in Cloudflare. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020991331-Adding-vendor-specific-DNS-records-to-Cloudflare

Answer (score 1):

I think you have things somewhat confused.
It looks like you are editing a hosted zone in AWS Route53, while it sounds like what you want is to change the delegation to use Cloudflare nameservers instead (making that AWS hosted zone redundant in the process).

Ie, you want to [make changes in the *registered domains* part of the Route53 UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-name-servers-glue-records.html#domain-name-servers-glue-records-adding-changing), not the *hosted zones* part of the Route53 UI.

Comment: Hi, that's right, I want to use Cloudflare as my DNS provider while having the domain purchased with Amazon. If I go to the `Registered Domain` area I have the option to Edit the domain, if I click it, it takes me to `Hosted zones` and then I'm back where I started

Comment: @Arturo Added a link with details, however, to my knowledge it's just "Edit name servers" or something like that.

Comment: That link doesn't even mention the `SOA` record :/ If you see my image, I have a field there to input the `SOA` value but no clue what to put from CloudFlare

Comment: @Arturo Can you elaborate on what the `SOA` record has to do with anything? Based on what you are trying to do, it sounds like the `SOA` record is not a factor.

Comment: Look at this image: https://i.postimg.cc/nVGjFCpV/Screen-Shot-2021-01-18-at-5-18-44-PM.png if you see there, I have a `SOA` record that I cannot delete. It also expects some value, what do I write there so it's coming from cloudflare? or do I even need to change it? Because right now it's referencing AWS

Comment: @Arturo That is a screenshot of the editing UI for an AWS Route53 Hosted Zone. The hosted zone is the thing you are getting rid of and replacing with Cloudflare, ie whatever you enter here will not be used by anything anymore once you switch. Just change the delegation to use the Cloudflare nameservers.